# Listing the elements of a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have an exercise as follows:
Let $A = \{1,3,12,35\}$, $B = \{3,7,12,20\}$, and $C = \{x | x\ is\ a\ prime \ number\}$. I have to list the elements of: $(A \cup B) \setminus C$. I used the
distributive law to get: $(A \setminus C)\cup(B \setminus C)$, then as follows:
$\{1, 12, 35\} \cup \{12,20\} = \{1,12,20,35\}$. Am I wrong with the solution and where if so? Thanks.

Comment: That looks totally right. How do you know you're wrong?

Comment: It seems like there is a language issue here.  You seem to mean to ask "*Am I wrong with the solution?*" but you wrote it like a statement "*I am wrong with the solution.*"  The first sentence is a question implying you are asking for information as to whether or not your attempt is correct or incorrect.  The second sentence is a statement which states that your answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$A \cup B = \{ 1,3, 7, 12, 20, 35\}$$

$C$ is the set of prime numbers. $3$ and $7$ are prime number in $A \cup B$.

Hence

$$(A \cup B)\setminus C = \{ 1, 12, 20, 35\}. $$

Your answer is fine.

Answer (score 1):

But you have complicated. You don't have to use distribute law. Just make first $A\cup B$ and then take away all the primes.